# How to create a method which is related with other created class

Tags: java

I have two classes (Person and Payment) and I struggle with their communication.
So can you show me how I can write a method Process which checks if given person exists? Also, I don't understand how I should take information from cmd and call a creatPeople and process methods in the main method.

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private double salary;



    boolean adjustSalary(double money, String type) {
        if (type.equals("+")) {
            salary = salary + money;
            return true;
        } else if (type.equals("-")) {
            if (salary > 0) {
                salary = salary - money;
                return true;
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("Wrong adjustment type!");
        return false;
    }



}

class Payment {
    static Person[] people;
    static int success = 0;
    static int fail = 0;

    static void createPeople(String[][] personInfo) {
        people = new Person[personInfo.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {
            Person x = new Person();
            people[i] = x;
        }
    }

    static void process(String[] Info) {
        Person obj = new Person();
        System.out.println(obj.adjustSalary);
        if (obj.adjustSalary == true)
            success++;
        else
            fail++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: owow, please indent, you're code is not readable^^

Comment: Sorry :( i'm new here, I left only the important part

Answer (score 1):

You can use a process called composition. This is the idea that one object1 must have another instance of an object2 in its constructor that way in order to create object1 you must ensure that you have an object2! Lmk if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your Person class must provide access to its members. You have to implement getters and setters. e.g.:

```
public void setName(String name){
   this.name = name; 
}

public String getName(){
   return this.name;
}

setSurname(String surname){
   this.surname = surname; 
}

public String getSurname(){
   return this.surname;
}

...
```

In your Payment class put the following method:

```
static boolean personIsKnown(Person person) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(Person _person: people){
        if(_person.getName().toUpperCase().equals(person.getName().toUpperCase()) &&
           _person.getSurname().toUpperCase().equals(person.getSurname().toUpperCase())) {

           found = true;
           break;
       }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Whenever you now call personIsKnown() you can find out whether a person exists in your array or not.

This is just for the start.

Comment: It could be a good idea to implement . equals () in Person class. This will help with check in for loop.

Comment: @contrapost: You're right. But I didn't want to make it to complicated.

Comment: Maybe it's better to learn traditional structure of the class from the very beginning: fields, getters/setters, toString () and equals(). And learn about hashCode() afterwards. But as "straight away answer" it should be good enough.